# Test fails because of missing assembly created at runtime

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nunit

I´m using Visual NUnit to build and run my tests together with NSubstitute. When I try to debug a single test having a breakpoint at its top execution does not break at all, however the test fails and throws

> System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'MyAssembly_Accessor' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

I already re-built the orivate accessor as described on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms184796%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) including these steps:

1. delete private accessor (right-click in Solution-Navigator --> delete)
2. rebuild assembly under test
3. re-create accessor
4. re-create whole source-code-file and copy-pasted original test-code to newly created file.

Did I miss anything?

Comment: Please change the tag. Visual NUnit is not NUnit although admittedly the name is confusing.

Comment: @Charlie I´m alwqys a bit reluctant on creating new tags as Visual NUnit doesn´t currently exist.